# POST request working on local but not on server

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-post, mapping, angular5

My app has some code about uploading files. Client fetches files and appends them to a POST http request, looks like this:

```
let formdata: FormData = new FormData();

formdata.append('file', file);

const req = new HttpRequest('POST', 'api/reports/post', formdata, {
        reportProgress: true,
        responseType: 'text'
});

return this.http.request(req);
```

Server will then receive the request like:

```
@PostMapping("/reports/post")
public ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUpload(
    @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
}
```

I get a 417 error, expectations not met, and apparently it's directly related to the way the parameters are passed, as GET methods do work alright on server.

I (kind of) know that Post request appended data should be encapsulated on a DTO Model on arrival, but my question is, why does local accept the POST requestes like this but my server won't? Thanks you in advance.

Comment: `this is not working` is not a clear problem. Add more explanation on what exactly doesn't work. Like http result code and/or error stack trace

Comment: What's the IP address of your server (check the `application.properties`).

Comment: I updated my post, 417 error as expectations are not met. I'm sorry I couldn't find the log file on this server. If anyone has the answer as to why POST requests could work when mapped as GET methods on localhost but not on a server you are very welcome. In the meanwhile I'm just going to adjust the mapping to a DTO model.